# in R, if matrix select first elements row-wise, if vector select first elements

Tags: r, matrix, vector, subset

Is there elegant R syntax to select, depending on the type of object, either the first `n` elements from a matrix row-wise, or the first `n` elements of a vector.

I can obviously do this with conditional statements, but I wonder if there is a simple solution. I also want to avoid calling `t()` on the whole matrix due to efficiency concerns.

```
M = matrix(1:12,3,4)
x = 1:12

slct = function(obj,n){
  if(is.matrix(obj)) res = c(t(obj))[1:n]
  if(is.vector(obj)) res = obj[1:n]
  res
}
slct(M,5); slct(x,5)
```

Comment: Regarding the conditional statements, use simply `as.vector(object)` or `c(object)`. However, I don't think you can work around the transpose unfortunately. So, the best answer I see is something along the lines of: `c(t(object))[1:n]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So avoiding calling `t()` on the whole matrix is the key. I think the other solutions are more interesting and pedagogical, but the fastest one I see is the following.

Efficiency is probably just because these rely on C subroutines to do the same vectorization as others suggest. Probably if you need only a specific subset of the elements 1:n there are cases where it would be faster to modify the other methods.

I still wonder if there is some builtin that does this?

Here are my two solutions (thanks to some ideas from the other posts):

```
funOPmod2 = function(obj,n){
  if(is.matrix(obj)){ 
    nc = ncol(obj)
    nr = (n %/% nc) + 1
    subM = obj[1:nr,]
    res = matrix(subM, ncol = nr,
                 byrow = TRUE)[1:n] }
  if(is.vector(obj)) res = obj[1:n]
  res
}

funOPmod = function(obj,n){
  if(is.matrix(obj)){ 
    nc = ncol(obj)
    nr = (n %/% nc) + 1
    res = t(obj[1:nr,])[1:n] }
  if(is.vector(obj)) res = obj[1:n]
  res
}

funOP = function(obj,n){
  if(is.matrix(obj)) res = c(t(obj))[1:n]
  if(is.vector(obj)) res = obj[1:n]
  res
}


funRyan <- function(x, n){
  if(is.vector(x)) i <- 1:n
  if(is.matrix(x))
    i <- cbind(ceiling(1:n/ncol(x)), rep_len(seq(ncol(x)), n))
  x[i]
}

funEmil <- function(obj, n) {
  myDim <- dim(obj)
  vec <- 1:n
  if (is.null(myDim))
    return(obj[vec])

  nr <- myDim[1]
  nc <- myDim[2]
  vec1 <- vec - 1L
  rem <- vec1 %% nc
  quot <- vec1 %/% nc
  obj[quot + (rem * nr + 1L)]
}

n <- 25000

set.seed(42)
MBig <- matrix(sample(10^7, 10^6, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10^4)

## Returns same results
all.equal(funOPmod2(MBig, n), funOP(MBig, n))
all.equal(funOPmod(MBig, n), funOP(MBig, n))
all.equal(funOP(MBig, n), funEmil(MBig, n))
all.equal(funRyan(MBig, n), funEmil(MBig, n))



library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(funOP(MBig, n), funOPmod(MBig, n), funOPmod2(MBig, n), funRyan(MBig, n), funEmil(MBig, n), unit = "relative")

Unit: relative
               expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval
     funOP(MBig, n) 13.788456 13.343185 15.776079 13.104634 15.064036 13.1959488   100
  funOPmod(MBig, n)  1.052210  1.089507  1.071219  1.118461  1.025714  0.4533697   100
 funOPmod2(MBig, n)  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.0000000   100
   funRyan(MBig, n)  2.689417  2.694442  2.464471  2.637720  2.351565  0.9274931   100
   funEmil(MBig, n)  2.760368  2.681478  2.434167  2.591716  2.308087  0.8921837   100
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
slct = function(obj,n){
  if(is.matrix(obj)) res = as.vector(matrix(M, dim(M),
                                            byrow = TRUE))[1:n]
  if(is.vector(obj)) res = obj[1:n]
  res
}
> slct(M,5); slct(x,5)
[1] 1 5 9 2 6
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Seems to be twice as fast according to benchmark:

```
Unit: microseconds
   expr   min    lq     mean median    uq       max neval cld
    t() 7.654 8.420 9.077494  8.675 8.675 10440.259 1e+05   b
 matrix 3.316 3.827 4.411272  4.082 4.083  9502.881 1e+05  a
```

*Note:* You should specify `is.vector` rather than `is.numeric` in second line, since `is.numeric(M)` yields `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of array-indexes in `[`.

```
# new function
slct2 <- function(x, n){
  if(is.vector(x)) i <- 1:n
  if(is.matrix(x))
    i <- cbind(ceiling(1:n/ncol(mat)), rep_len(seq(ncol(mat)), n))
  x[i]
}
# old function
slct = function(obj,n){
  if(is.matrix(obj)) res = c(t(obj))[1:n]
  if(is.vector(obj)) res = obj[1:n]
  res
}
```

Benchmark

```
m <- 1e4
mat <- matrix(runif(m^2), m)
n <- floor(m*2.3)
all.equal(slct(mat, n), slct2(mat, n))
# [1] TRUE
microbenchmark(slct(mat, n), slct2(mat, n), times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#           expr         min          lq        mean      median         uq        max neval
#   slct(mat, n) 2471.438599 2606.071460 3466.046729 3137.255011 4420.69364 4985.20781    10
#  slct2(mat, n)    2.358151    4.748712    6.627644    4.973533   11.05927   13.73906    10
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use `head`?...

```
head(c(t(M)),5)
[1]  1  4  7 10  2

head(c(t(x)),5)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution that does not call t(), at least on the whole matrix...

Answer (score 0):

Here is base R solution:

```
funEmil <- function(obj, n) {
    myDim <- dim(obj)
    vec <- 1:n
    if (is.null(myDim))
        return(obj[vec])

    nr <- myDim[1]
    nc <- myDim[2]
    vec1 <- vec - 1L
    rem <- vec1 %% nc
    quot <- vec1 %/% nc
    obj[quot + (rem * nr + 1L)]
}
```

It relies on basic vectorized modular arithmetic `%%` and integer division `%/%`.  It is also very fast:

```
set.seed(42)
MBig <- matrix(sample(10^7, 10^6, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10^4)

funOP = function(obj,n){
    if(is.matrix(obj)) res = c(t(obj))[1:n]
    if(is.vector(obj)) res = obj[1:n]
    res
}

funRyan <- function(x, n){
    if(is.vector(x)) i <- 1:n
    if(is.matrix(x))
        i <- cbind(ceiling(1:n/ncol(x)), rep_len(seq(ncol(x)), n))
    x[i]
}


n <- 25000

## Returns same results
all.equal(funRyan(MBig, n), funEmil(MBig, n))
[1] TRUE

all.equal(funOP(MBig, n), funEmil(MBig, n))
[1] TRUE

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(funOP(MBig, n), funRyan(MBig, n), funWoody(MBig, n), unit = "relative")
Unit: relative
             expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
   funOP(MBig, n) 6.154284 5.915182 5.659250 5.880826 9.140565 1.0344393   100
 funRyan(MBig, n) 1.015332 1.030278 1.028644 1.018446 1.032610 0.8330967   100
 funEmil(MBig, n) 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.0000000   100
```

Here are the benchmarks using the example by @Ryan and the OP's modified solution:

```
n <- 1e4
mat <- matrix(runif(n^2), n)
s <- floor(n*2.3)

microbenchmark(funOP(mat, s), funRyan(mat, s), 
               funWoody(mat, s), funOPmod(mat, s), unit = "relative", times = 10)
Unit: relative
            expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
   funOP(mat, s) 6189.449838 5558.293891 3871.425974 5139.192594 2443.203331 2222.778805    10
 funRyan(mat, s)    2.633685    3.032467    2.155205    2.863710    1.445421    1.537473    10
 funEmil(mat, s)    2.654739    2.714287    1.969482    2.642673    1.277088    1.326510    10
funOPmod(mat, s)    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    10
```

The new modified is much faster and still give correct results.. very impressive!!

```
identical(funOPmod(mat, s), funRyan(mat, s))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote??? An explanation would be nice as I could address any deficiencies in my answer.

Comment: @user36302, many thanks... I thought your modified solution is by far the best answer as it is very concise and the fastest.